# How do i make it possible to make two fields mandatory(data validation) and in the message show that both should be filled?

Tags: c#

i want to make sure the user doesnot leave the boxes empty. But i am only able to show one box name in the message but want to show in the message box that both should be filled! How do i do that?

I tried but don't know how to show the message that both fields are mandatory. If one is empty than it should be filled too!!

```
            {
                string unitName = txtUnitName.Text;

                if (unitName.Trim() == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unit Name is mandatory!!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    return;
                }

                else
                {
                    string alias = txtAlias.Text;
                    if (alias.Trim() == string.Empty)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(" Alias is mandatory!!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        return;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply show a message if any of the two fields is empty, and you can check that directly without moving them to extra variables or using `trim`:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUnitName.Text) 
 || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAlias.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unit Name and Alias are mandatory!!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    return;
}
```

Of course, depending on the framework you are using (WPF, MVC) there may be better (or ore elegant) ways to implement field validation,

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to highlight all remaining error messages.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls) {
   if (ctrl Is TextBoxBase) {
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ctrl.Text)) {
          sb.AppendLine(ctrl.Name.Substring(3) + " is mandatory.");
       }
   }
}
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning); 
return;
```

You could use a `List<string>` instead of `StringBuilder` if you want.

> A better way is using BindingSource controls and bind the validation labels' visible property to fields in the business object.

*Disclaimer: Typed on my phone.*